# What is the probability of $P(X+Y=1)$?

Tags: probability, convolution

$X$~$Exp(1.4)$ and $Y$~$Exp(2.8)$ are independent. What is the probability of $P(X+Y=1)$. I've tried to use the convolution theorem but I couldn't figure it out.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: where "exp" is? Moreover, the variables are independent?

Comment: @Exodd Yes they are independent, sorry, correcting the question

Comment: How is the exponential distribution defined for you?

Comment: Hint: If both variables has density, then due to independence, vector $(X,Y)$ has density, too. But the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x+y =1 \}$ is of measure $0$

Comment: Exponential random variables should have only 1 parameter, not 2. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution

Comment: @KingJ They have, those meant to be decimal points and not commas. thank you ,edited

Comment: Please show your work, whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are meant to be working with exponential and not Poisson random variables, the sum of two independent exponential random variables is distributed according to the Gamma distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). Note that since you have a continuous distribution the probability of hitting any one point is 0.

For this reason I will mention the Poisson case. The sum of Poisson random variables is again Poisson with parameter being the sum of parameters (in this case $1.4+2.8=4.2$). You can then use the known formula for a Poisson random variable to find the solution.